# How to combine GROUP BY and JOIN statements in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to combine a query I have run on one table with some columns on another table. The query I ran calculates the total of something for me by this:

```
SELECT security.Loan_id
     , SUM(security.SecMktValue) AS TotalSecMktValue
  FROM security 
 GROUP 
    BY Loan_id
 ORDER 
    BY loan_id ASC;
```

I then tried to join this query with columns from another table by:

```
SELECT loans.Loan_id, loans.TotalLoanAmt
FROM loans
JOIN(SELECT SUM(security.SecMktValue) AS TotalSecMktValue,security.Loan_id
FROM security
GROUP BY Loan_id ASC)
ON loans.Loan_id = security.Loan_id;
```

However, this wont run as it says there is an error with my SQL syntax even though nothing is underlined in red. Does anyone know why that is?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an alias:

```
SELECT loans.Loan_id, loans.TotalLoanAmt
FROM loans
JOIN(
    SELECT SUM(security.SecMktValue) AS TotalSecMktValue,security.Loan_id
    FROM security
    GROUP BY Loan_id ASC
    ) security -- <-- here
ON loans.Loan_id = security.Loan_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL requires an alias to be assigned to the derived table (i.e. a correlation name associated with the inline view). The qualifier `security` is out of scope outside the inline view i.e. it's not a valid reference in the outer query.)

Here's an example, assigning the alias `t` to the derived table. Notice that in the outer query, references to columns from the inline view are qualified with `t.`

```
SELECT l.loan_id
     , l.totalloanamt
     , t.totalsecmktvalue
  FROM loans l
  LEFT
  JOIN ( 
         SELECT s.loan_id
              , SUM(s.secmktvalue) AS totalsecmktvalue
           FROM security s
          GROUP
             BY s.loan_id
       ) t
    ON t.loan_id = l.loan_id
 ORDER
    BY l.loan_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got you question right then this should work  :)

```
SELECT security.Loan_id,SUM(security.SecMktValue) AS TotalSecMktValue
  FROM security security
  JOIN loans loan 
  ON loans.Loan_id = security.Loan_id
  GROUP BY Loan_id ASC
```